# SQLAlchemy how LazyLoading works

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hi I would like to understand how does sqlalchemy lazy loading works? Assuming I have this query

```
results = (
        session.query(Parent).
            options(lazyload(Parent.children)).
            filter(Parent.id == 1).
            all()
    )

    for parent in results:
        logging.error(parent.children)
```

I want to know if I access the parent.children on the for loop will this create a new select statement? or is the record or parent.children already cached or something? I'm thinking of how this will affect the performance. I just want to most optimize way.

1. Should I use lazyloading?
2. Will accessing per item on the loop create a new sqlalchemy
3. How do I find out if a query is being run by sqlalchemy? (Just want to find out if accessing per entry will create a select statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Maybe.
2. Do you mean issue a new query? The answer is [yes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html), that's the point of [`lazyload()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#lazy-loading). The relationship collection attribute is populated when first accessed, lazily. If on the other hand you'd wish to avoid the possible N+1 situation, you could for example use [`joinedload()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) instead in order to populate children in the same query.
3. Use [logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo). Pass `echo=True` in your engine configuration.